# Need help understanding routing order

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've got a few feature modules, each with a routing module in it. The problem I'm running into is kind of want to do a catchall, and it's not behaving how I expect, and I'm not sure why.

I want to set up something where I have a few specific route matches, like `/ucp`, `/`, `/admin`, and anything entered into the first segment would otherwise match to a final ruleset.

In my app-routing module, I have:

```
{
    path: 'admin',
    component: AdminComponent,
},
{
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
    path: '',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
},
```

Then, for example, in my ucp routing module, I have

```
{
    path: 'ucp',
    component: UcpComponent,
}
```

And in my org module, I have

```
{
    path: ':org',
    component: OrgComponent,
}
```

And when importing into my app module, I have them in the following order:

```
imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    UcpModule,
    OrgModule,
]
```

`/ucp` and `/admin` work fine, but everything else gets directed to the OrgComponent. I would expect since '' has `pathMatch: 'full'`, it should catch and direct to the home component, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I'm getting confused if the router matches by first match, best match, or what. Obviously the order of the modules matters, as when I had the UcpModule under the OrgModule, `/ucp` was always caught by the OrgComponent.

I don't know if my misunderstanding how to setup my router modules or theres a trick here I'm missing. Hell, I wish I could figure out how to regex a match to determine if it's valid (I'd love to be able to distinguish between a string and a number for different components), but that's a different question altogether.